# Find points forming lines using Hough transform

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I have a dataset and I would like to group the points forming lines parallel to the Y axis (see image). I guess the way to do it is by using the Hough transform; do you have any suggestion of how to do it in Matlab?

[image]

Comment: Where are the lines, in your opinion ? If you asked me to draw the ground truth, I'd be well embarrassed.

Comment: The lines should be parallel to the Y axis. I updated the question.

Comment: Your choice looks rather arbitrary and just showing two cases is not enough. Can you show ALL the lines ? [My bet is that you just couldn't in a reproducible way.] If they are exactly vertical, the first thing to do is to project all points on the horizontal size and observe the local points density. You can estimate the modes of the distribution using a Parzen window. (Actually, this is a fixed-angle version of the Hough transform.)

Comment: Well, I don't know all the lines because I have to find them ;) (the dots are the coordinates of the center of mass of different shapes)

Comment: Is there a logical reason why these centers are aligned ? And why is the point cloud so messy ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy

Comment: @chappjc - Couldn't have said it any better.  I think those y-axis "lines" are pulling something from nothing.  Going with the OP's definition of how the points are grouped, there would be many lines parallel to the y-axis that would be considered as a group, but by going with the colour scheme (which I'm assuming differentiates between the datasets), this would be a poor clustering.

Comment: A possibly relevant question on [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32063/automated-procedure-for-selecting-subset-of-data-points-w-strongest-correlation), and [an article by Loren Shure](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/11/21/subset-selection-and-regularization/) might be helpful.

Comment: Hi guys, yes there is a reason why the points should form lines: each point represents the CM of a blob inside a cylindrical sample. As the sample is rotated around its axis, the CM of the blob moves along a line (1D projection of a circle).

Comment: @albus_c what are the axis of your scatter plot? is it time vs. angle? what is the meaning of the different colors of the points?

Comment: @Shai The axis of the plot are the Y and X (axis are flipped) axis of the detector. The colours show different intensity values, where by intensity I mean the number of pixels constituting a certain blob. So on X and Y we have the coordinates of the CM for each blob, and in colorscale we have the number of pixels per blob.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the restriction, only to detect lines parallel to the y axis, a full hough transform is not necessary. Just project all points on the x-axis accumulate them and find peaks.

```
%assuming you want a resolution of 0.01 covering x space from 0 to 1
points = rand(1000,2);
figure(1);
plot(points(:,1),points(:,2),'b.');
minX = 0;
maxX = 1;
resolution = 0.01;
xValues = minX:resolution:maxX;
accu = zeros(1,length(xValues));
for i = 1:length(points)
    xVal = points(i,1); % access x value of point;
    idx = round(((xVal-minX)/resolution))+1;
    accu(idx) = accu(idx) +1;
end
```

Now you have an accumulator where you can search for maximas.

```
[pks,idx] = findpeaks(accu);
```

You might only want to consider peaks with at least `minPoints` points:

```
minPoints = 10;
idx = idx(pks>minPoints);
```

Then you can process this lines further:

```
for i = 1:length(idx)
    % select all points corresponding to line:
    idc = abs(points(:,1)-xValues(idx(i))) < resolution/2;
    pointsOnLine = points(idc,:);
    figure(1);
    hold on;
    plot(pointsOnLine(:,1),pointsOnLine(:,2),'ro');
    minY = min(pointsOnLine(:,2));
    maxY = max(pointsOnLine(:,2));
    plot([xValues(idx(i)),xValues(idx(i))],[minY,maxY],'r-');
end
```

To remove lines with large gaps, you can use `sort()` to sort the points according to their y values and then find large jumps with `diff`.